# How does the next command actually function

Tags: awk

I get (FILENAME=123.dat FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted error in the following script. Doesn't the next command ignore the following two blocks of code and start executing the code for the 2nd record. If that isn't the case how can I ïgnore any code execution on the first record of a file?

```
awk ' BEGIN {

FS="<[^>]+>"; 
RS="";
review1=1;
review2=1;
rating=0;
criteria=7;


}

#ignores the first record of each file
FNR<2 { next }  

FNR==NR {

#sums all the ratings of an authors
for(i=8; i<=14;i++) {
    rating+=$i;     
}

    #stores the average rating of each author
    sum1+=rating/criterias;

    #stores each average rating
    total1[review1]=rating/criteria

    review1++;
    rating=0;   
} 

FNR!=NR {

.... code

}

END {

#calculates the mean(overall rating) for hotel1
mean1=sum1/review1;

printf("Mean hotel_1: %.2f\n",mean1);

} ' "$2" "$3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get (FILENAME=123.dat FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted error
>   in the following script.

```
sum1+=rating/criterias;
```

`criterias` is not defined so you get above error.

**How does the next command actually function**

> The next statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the
>   current record and go on to the next record. This means that no
>   further rules are executed for the current record, and the rest of the
>   current rule’s action isn’t executed.

**FNR and NR**

> When awk reads from the multiple input file, awk NR variable will give
>   the total number of records relative to all the input file. Awk FNR
>   will give you number of records for each input file.

**If that isn't the case how can I ïgnore any code execution on the first record of a file?**

What you did already `FNR<2 { next }` is correct, you can also write it as `FNR==1{ next }`, no rules will be executed when `awk` reads first record of each file.